# Convert Array elements into single strings (PHP)

Tags: php

So basically, I use this to retrieve data

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
$user = $this->oDb->selectQuery($sql);
```

^^ that is this:

```
$aResult = array();
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $aResult[] = $row;
        }
        return $aResult;
```

So that would return this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 [voornaam] => Franklin [tv] => Delano [achternaam] => Roosevelt ) )
```

How do I convert Franklin which is 'voornaam'
and Delano which is 'tv'
and Roosevelt which is 'achternaam'

```
to either $user['voornaam']
$user['tv']
$user['achternaam']

so it would result in echo $user['voornaam'] which would say Franklin

or either $voornaam
$tv
$achternaam

or it would result in echo $voornaam which would say Franklin
```

Comment: `extract()` but don't do that, just use the arrays. Unless maybe you are creating a templte?

Comment: @AbraCadaver well, I use the values for my edit user form, so that the default values are already in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $aResult[0]['voornaam'];
```

But this will only work, if you fetch just one row. (Not sure without trying, but I think you're whole code just works for returning only one row, because you always reassign the first element of the result)

Regarding you're other comment it is of course `echo $whatEverYouPutTheResultInto[0]['voornaam']`

Comment: That worked. Solved! the problem was that it wasn't $aResult but rather $user because: $user = $this->oDb->selectQuery($sql);

Answer (score 0):

The result is already stored in an array.
You can simply call it like:

```
echo $aResult[0]['voornaam'];
```

which will give you output **Franklin**

Comment: Undefined variable: aResult